# Есть замечания по программе проверки ритмичности стихов?

Tags: словоизменение, поэзия, орфоэпия

Прошу Уважаемое Сообщество ознакомиться с [программой проверки ритмичности стихов](http://www.ritminme.ru/o-programme/kratkoe)

Шлифуя свои несовершенные стишки, я обнаружил, что в Сети есть люди, способные критически разобрать чужое творение. Но чаще всего они пользуются словами, качественно, эмоционально описывающими ситуацию. С доказательной базой обстоит очень слабо. Верхом того, что удалось обнаружить, явилась запись строк стиха в виде условных символов, обозначающих ударные и безударные слоги. Вот и подумалось: я программист - почему бы не написать программу, автоматизирующую процесс получения таких изображений? Для пущей наглядности - можно в цвете... Ну и занялся.

По ходу обнаружилось, что выдавать готовый вердикт на нынешнем уровне развития техники невозможно - для этого для этого программа должна понимать текст. В результате получил не лампочку с двумя состояниями ( горит - "шедевр", не горит - "УГ" ), а некое подобие панели управления автомобилем с несколькими индикаторами.

Наверное, поэтому я и называю окошко, расположенное справа от редактируемого текста, панелью, на которой можно включать те или иные индикаторы (регуляторы везде - в меню, вызываемым по правой клавише мыши). Народ на некоторых сайтах пользуется самым простым из них - количеством слогов в строке - и доволен... На сколько это удобно, что сделано хорошо, что нужно доработать, а то и добавить или убрать - другой вопрос.

На сегодняшний день программа умеет переводить неровные строчки стихов в более лаконичную графику - условными символами и слогами с цветовой разметкой. В некоторых случаях программе нужно помогать: она не знает логических ударений и фонетических слов. Это делается кликами по слогам в окне отображения ритмичности.

А потом - собственно использование. Если текст только пишется - смотрим, насколько он соответствует выбранному размеру, правим... Если с рифмой проблемы - лезем во встроенный рифмовник. Если занимаемся критиканством - оцениваем соответствие всего текста выбранному размеру и выбранной схеме рифмовки.

Для этого бывает удобно группы стихотворных строк обрамлять строками прозы. Чаще всего это пустые строки, или там с звёздочками какими, названием глав, всего произведения, датой сотворения и подписью автора... В этих строках в окне отображения ритмичности можно вывести линейку стихотворного размера. По умолчанию в ней отображается статистика, но можно задать и классический размер.

В конце концов, и ритм, и рифма - это существенное, но не основное в стихах. Основное - талант, вдохновение. А программа лишь облегчает рутинную работу... Если интересно - посмотрите, как я пользуюсь выдачей своей программы при работе с авторами: [примеры](http://www.ritminme.ru/sovremennost/)

Цель создания программы: дать удобный инструмент для анализа и написания стихов.

Сверхцель создания программы: ввести в обращение некий стандарт доказательного анализа стихотворных произведений.

FAQ:

Q: А кому это нужно?
A: Мне. Потому программа и существует.

Q: А ведь алгеброй гармонию поверять – нехорошо...
A: С мнением по этому поводу Великого Афро-Россиянина я знаком. Но не одобряю и не поддерживаю.

Q: Скормил программе стихи. В правой части экрана вижу какую-то расчленёнку. Что дальше делать?
A: Задаться вопросом – знаете ли Вы, как расставлять ударения? Если нет – программа, скорее всего, не для Вас. Если да – прочтите краткое наставление ( http://www.ritminme.ru/o-programme/kratkoe ) и дерзайте... На конкретные вопросы отвечу мейлом через ящик info сайта ritminme.ru.

Answer (score 1):

Скажите пожалуста, <s>а это и в магазине можно таким образом стеночку приподнять?</s> нет ли подобной программы для художественной прозы?

Comment: Не понял: что значит "подобной программы для художественной прозы"? Я подумывал сделать в программе страничку для прозы едино ради возможности ведения словаря пользователя - писателям, создающим собственные миры со своей географией и кучей имён это было бы полезно. Но насколько она будет востребована?